# Element edited in contenteditable mode with added line on click doesnt work on second line

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

If you edit this element add lines and click on first line it works, but if you click on second or third line it goes wrong. There is code I used.

JS:

```
$('.layer-text').append("<p class='textbox' contenteditable='true'>Click me</p>")

$("body").on('click', '.layer-text', function(e){

        if(!$(e.target).is('.textbox')) {

            $(".textbox").removeClass("active");
            alert("!textbox");

        }
});

$('.layer-text').on('click', '.textbox', function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        alert("is textbox");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class='layer-text'></div>
```

CSS:

```
body, .layer-text {width: 300px; height: 400px; background: #f0f0f0;}
.textbox.active {background: red;}
```

Thank you for help. Kasta

Comment: For this sort of thing, right-clicking the dynamically-generated content and choosing "Inspect element" in any modern browser is very useful to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're testing `e.target`, and the target of the event isn't the `p.textbox`, it's a `div` inserted by the browser.

You can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest):

```
if (!$(e.target).closest(".textbox").length) {
    // It's not a .textbox, and not *in* a .textbox
});
```

[Here's a live copy](http://jsbin.com/nubujede/1) of your original code, and [here's a live copy](http://jsbin.com/nubujede/2) with the change above.

Note that I'm assuming the `div.layer-text` is never put *inside* an element with the `textbox` class, since `closest` won't stop looking as of the `.layer-text` `div`. If you need to be that precise, you can use this instead:

```
if (!$(e.target).closest(".textbox, .layer-text").hasClass("textbox")) {
    // It's in a .layer-text, but not in a .textbox within a .layer-text
});
```